# branch spec issue

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-branch-spec

I am trying to port changelist "661234" from source to target branch using branch mapping "branch1.2_1.2.0" but I keep getting that its already commited but the changes are not merged actually..how can I overcome this?any tips on what the issue is?

I am been struggling since once hour trying various commands but no luck,appreicate any ehlp

```
C:\Users\>p4 integrate -b prima1.2_1.2.0 -c @661243
Invalid changelist number '@661243'.

C:\Users\>p4 integrate -b prima1.2_1.2.0 -c 661243
Change 661243 is already committed.

C:\Users\>p4 integrate -b prima1.2_1.2.0 -c 661243
Change 661243 is already committed.

C:\Users\>p4 integrate -f -b prima1.2_1.2.0 -c 661243
Change 661243 is already committed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, -c is the changelist to put the resulting change into, what you want is something like this:

```
p4 integrate -i -t -b prima1.2_1.2.0 //...@661243
```

Comment: still get the output as "change is already commited"..why is p4 thinking so?

Comment: for some files on the branch..am getting error like "cant integrate ...without -i flag"

Comment: -i allows integrations between files that have no integration history.  It permits baseless merges and just uses the earliest revision during p4 resolve.